# How to write clean url in reverse?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following in my my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^terms-and-conditions terms.php
RewriteRule ^privacy privacy.php
RewriteRule ^thank-you thanks.php
```

How could I also do this in reverse such as typing `/privacy.php` is rewritten as /privacy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 3 separate rules using `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable to avoid redirect loop:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+terms\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /terms-and-conditions [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+privacy\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /privacy [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+thanks\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /thank-you [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^terms-and-conditions/?$ terms.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^privacy/?$ privacy.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^thank-you/?$ thanks.php [L,NC]
```